# How to know 'When to take $\sin x=t$ in limit questions'?

Tags: limits

In all the question I never took $\sin x =t$ and was able to solve most of them but I got stack in this question and I saw the solution , I found that they took $\sin x =t$ and treated $\sin x$ as just a variable $t$. I found it a bit weird, now many question how would I had known that I had to take $\sin x$ as $t$ to solve this problem.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin (x) + \log\bigl(\sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}-\sin x\bigr)}{\sin^3(x)}$$

Comment: is it $\sqrt{1} or \sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)} or \sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)-\sin(x)}$?

Comment: It is √1+sin^2x and sin^3x is in denominator (in division)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that, in a neighborhood of $0$, the function $\sin x$ is continuous and invertible, so also its inverse is likewise continuous.

You can consider the function
$$
f(t)=\frac{t+\log(\sqrt{1+t^2}-t)}{t^3}
$$
and you have to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(\sin x)
$$
Because of the above fact, this is the same as
$$
\lim_{t\to0}f(t)
$$
exactly because the inverse of the sine function (in a neighborhood of $0$) is continuous. This is no different from
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\log x}{x-1}=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\log(1+t)}{t}
$$
with the substitution $t=x-1$, which is continuous and with continuous inverse.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use the fact that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(x)=\lim_{t \to 0} t =0.$$
Even more, $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}x=1$, so $\sin(x)$ behaves near $0$ just as $x$.

Therefore replacing $\sin x$ with $x$ does not change the limit.
This substitution is done, because polynomials are easier to handle than sums of potences of the sine.

If the expression of which you have to calculate the limit near $0$ only depends on $x$ through a function $g(x)$ (in your case the sine), it is a good strategy to ask, how this function $g$ behaves near $0$ and use this as an intermediate step.

Edit: If the term of which you take the limit also depends directly on $x$ or through another function, this is in general not possible as can be seen in the answer by Ross Milikan.

Comment: So, whenever x tends to o I should try taking sinx as x ,right?

Comment: only if the term only depends on $x$ through $\sin x$. Otherwise, some it is not possible in general, as can be seen in the answer by Ross Milikan. Think about $sin$ as the its series expansion and you can see the issues

Answer (score 0):

It will work as long as the first order terms do not cancel out and will often simplify your computations.  The problem comes if we ask $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {x-\sin x}{x^3}$$  If you blindly substitute in $\sin x=x$ you will get $0$ for the limit because the function is then identically $0$.  In truth the limit is $\frac 16$ because we care about the third order term.